# How to switch view before render current view?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I am using [Field Collection Views](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) module which allowed to create field widget as a view.

My requirement is to allow content author to choose widget for output this field (Field Collection). I added select field to article type to choose widget from two Field Collection Views views.

Field Collection is using [views_embed_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) for rendering this field, so I am trying to use [hook_views_pre_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7) to switch to different view if author choose other than default view (display formatter)

```
/*
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view()
 */
function wzp_gallery_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
    $node = menu_get_object();
    if (! $node->type == 'article') {
        return;
    }
    $field_name = FIELD_GALLERY_VIEW_FIELD_NAME;
    if (! $node->$field_name) {
        return;
    }
    $value = array_shift($node->$field_name);
    $view_info = explode('#', $value[0]['value']);
    if (! $view_info) {
        return;
    }
    $name = $view_info[0];
    $id = $view_info[1];
    if ($view->name == $name && $display_id == $id) {
        return;
    }
    $display_id = $id;
    if ($view->name == $name) {
        return;
    }
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($name, 1) . '</pre>');
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($id, 1) . '</pre>');
    $view = views_get_view($name);
    $view->set_display($id);
    $view->preview = TRUE;
}
```

but I am end up always with default view rendered.

Code form Field Collection Views module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function field_collection_views_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();
  $settings = $display['settings'];

  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'field_collection_views_view':
      //debug($items);
      $args = '';
      $i = 1;
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        if ($i == 1) {
          $args .= $item['value'];
        }
        else {
          $args .= '+' . $item['value'];
        }
        $i++;
      }
      $view_name = isset($settings['name']) ? $settings['name'] : 'field_collection_view';
      $display_id = isset($settings['display_id']) ? $settings['display_id'] : 'default';
      $content = views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id, $args);
      $element[0] = array(
        '#markup' => $content,
      );
      if (empty($items)) {
        field_collection_field_formatter_links($element, $entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display);
      }
      break;
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Could someone give me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

You can't switch view during render process but current display id.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use hook_views_pre_view, see the documentation here:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7

Hope this helps, I had a similar use case. Note: you should use

```
$view->set_display()
```

To actually change the view display.